# How to select div1~divN,where N is a variable with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, selector

```
<div class="target"> </div>
...
<div class="target"> </div>
```

`$('div.target:eq(0),...div.target:eq(N-1)')` only works when `N` is a constant,but in my case `N` is a variable..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very fast way is to [use `.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

```
$('div.target').slice( 0, N );
```

This will be faster than using selectors, especially since selectors like `:lt()` are not valid CSS selectors, and as such are not useful [for `querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), which jQuery (Sizzle) utilizes whenever possible.

Comment: As a general practice, this nicely avoids dynamically creating selectors which (while possible) is unnecessarily complex, unstable, and slow.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [lt selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).

```
$('.target:lt(' + N + ')');
```

Comment: So what you mean is your selecting a range?  Not a specific index?

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.target').each(function(i, item){

   // $(item) is a div
   // i = div index  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divPrefix = 'n-',
    suffix=0,
    elements = [];

while(element = document.getElementById(DivPrefix + suffix++)){
    elements.push(element);
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, misunderstood question